# How can I get a reference to a object in the world in UE4?

Tags: c++, unreal, unreal-4

I'm coding a simple maze game in UE4 and I have everything I wanted to implement done except having an obstacle in the scene. What I have is a simple `Obstacle` class which is a child of an `Actor` class.

Now in the scene I have a `Blueprint` which is a child of the `Obstacle` class and this `Blueprint` is placed in the maze. What I'm trying to achieve is when the player collects so many objects (let's say 10) then the `Obstacle` will be destroyed but I don't know how to get a reference to that `Obstacle` object in my code.

```
AObstacle* Obstacle /////// This is where I don't know how to initialize the object
if (MyCharacter->collectedPickUps >= requiredAmountOfPickups)
{
    Obstacle->Destroy();
    Obstacle->isActive = false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have managed to sort it out. Basically I have to use an Actor Iterator which iterates through every Obstacle object in the game world. Here is the code:

```
for (TActorIterator<AObstacle> ObstacleItr(GetWorld()); ObstacleItr; ++ObstacleItr)
{
    if (MyCharacter->collectedPickUps >= requiredAmountOfPickups)
    {
        ObstacleItr->Destroy();
        ObstacleItr->bIsActive = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There must be a solution better than this, in Unity you can reference that Actor(GameObject) by exposing a GameObject variable, then dragging the desired GameObject to that variable, just don't know how to make it in UE4 :S

Comment: After weeks of struggling, just make a public UPROPERTY AActor* targetActor, in the editor, when selecting that object select targetActor intended actor from the dropdown list;

Comment: @AhmedU3 Thank you so much! This should be the answer!

Comment: @Ahmed, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Okay;

In unity, to refer a gameobject in the scene directly you can declare a "public GameObject targetObject", then it becomes easy to drag&drop it in the inspector.


To make the same in UE4, you need to declare "public: UPROPERTY(...) AActor* targetActor;"

by building this, if you go to the editor > select your object > in the details isA you'll find a dropdown list which contains all the actors